# SQL Query Count results as zero event record is not exist

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count

I have an issue to an SQL Query (Oracle database).

I have two tables. One table is "ACCIDENTS " and the other is "REASONS". This second is table has some predefined default values.

```
 - REASONS -

Reason 1
Reason 2
Reason 3
Reason 4
```

Now in the ACCIDENTS table we insert some accidents and reasons from the previous table like below

```
 - ACCIDENTS -

Accident 1  - Reason 1
Accident 2  - Reason 1
Accident 3  - Reason 4
```

**All I want to get the count of accidents GROUP BY all 4 reasons even if a reason does not exist in ACCIDENTS table. In this case I want to get Count = 0 like below:**

```
REASONS   COUNT (of Accidents)
Reason 1    2
Reason 2    0
Reason 3    0
Reason 4    1
```

Unsuccessfully I have already tried different type of JOIN tables but I don't get as results Reason 2 and Reason 3 because they don't exist in ACCIDENTS table. Every time the result is:

```
REASONS   COUNT (of Accidents)
Reason 1    2
Reason 4    1
```

Any solutions/thoughts ?

Thanks in advance!

---

**UPDATE !**

This is the query:

```
SELECT R.REASON_NAME AS REASON, COUNT(A.ID) AS COUNT_OF_ACCIDENTS
FROM ACCIDENTS A
RIGHT JOIN REASONS R ON R.ID = A.REASON_ID
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FPOM A.DATE_OF_ACCIDENT) = 2017
GROUP BY R.REASON_NAME
```

If i remove the WHERE statement then I get all REASONS correctly but the Where for Year in Accidents table is mandatory.

Comment: It looks like you just want an outer join, but please edit your question to show the current query. Might be helpful to include one with a different type of join you tried, so we can see where you're going wrong.

Comment: Updated my question with my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `left join` and aggregation:

```
select r.reason, count(a.reason)
from reasons r left join
     accidents a
     on r.reason = a.reason and
        a.date_of_accident >= date '2017-01-01' and
        a.date_of_accident < date '2018-01-01'
group by r.reason;
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. That is correct! But I updated my question. I also have a where in my query that causes the problem. Can you please check again ?

Comment: @ktsigkounis . . . You need to move that condition to the `ON` clause.

Comment: That's the solution! :) Thanks a lot!